# how do you look at the contents of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript. When I do a typeof variable name, I get object{}. I need to look at the contents of this object. How would I do that in javascript?

Comment: Use developer tools, e.g. firebug.

Comment: Click on that `object{}`.

Comment: Uh, can you show us what exaclty you do with `typeof`, and where you enter that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what envrionment you're talking about? Are you in the browser, in Node, in a Phonegap app, etc?

Comment: @Paul, I am using chrome. I am trying to assign the values in object to another variable. I need to see what the object looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use developer's console (Chrome console / Firebug / etc) or just convert your object to string:

```
var objAsString = JSON.stringify(yourVariable);
```

Comment: when I do data=JSON.stringify(data); I get {}. How do look inside of {}?

Comment: If you're getting {} then it's an empty object, there is nothing inside it.